# Best settings for MP4 for Web / iPhone / iPad / Android

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, flash, mp4

I have a stock trading membership website, on which I put up stock videos on stock trading days. Currently, I have them in **.swf** and I am quiet happy with what I offer. Lately, my members are asking for availability on ***iPhone / iPad*** too, which means, I have to convert or upload new videos in one of the universally accepted formats, i.e., **.mp4**. I have tested few settings with the video conversion, but, up to, *640 x 480* resolution worked well on ***iPhone / iPad*** but for ***web viewing***, it was disaster. I usually offer videos in 980 x 620 size. I changed the size to 800 x 600 and it was Okay for *web*, but *iPhone / iPad* din't do well. I am using *JWPlayer* for the test.

I want to ask, what format of the video should I use, which will work for all platforms. I want to keep the video size down, and as well 1 file for all platforms. Is there anything that I can do to achieve this?

Will be very thankful if someone helps me out on this.

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at HTML 5 video. That will work on iPhone and Android. This site allegedly helps with javascript libraries to display HTML 5 or Flash depending on what is available/compatible. http://html5video.org/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is really a code related issue but since I'm here:

Definitely use mp4 it works on all your desired platforms.

Definately stick with JWPlayer, I use it to stream to web and iPhone.

To keep the "file size down" and if you are encoding offline use handbrake http://handbrake.fr/

Using that software you will see some pre-sets for iDevices including iPhone and iPod mp4 / m4v file output. A new version of the software has just been released so it may include a pre-set for iPad too.

Personally I have a pre-set that is 720x400 which runs on iPod touch 2ndGen and iPhone very well.

Unfortunately one file does not suit all your target platforms. However, with JWPlayer you are able set it up with bitrate switching such that the best possible version of the different video files is delivered to the target platform:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v4/27/bitrate-switching

The JWPlayer will also deliver to Flash and HTML5 enabled browsers.